# Handling Custom Error Pages(404, 500) In Django

Tags: django

Why when I click on the page does not exist imposed error page appears in the project folder but I see the emergence of the page django with all the code is true

```
from django.shortcuts import (
render_to_response
)
from django.template import RequestContext

def handler404(request, exception):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    err_code = 404
    response = render_to_response('404.html', {"code":err_code}, context)
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
def handler500(request, exception):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    err_code = 500
    response = render_to_response('500.html', {"code":err_code}, context)
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If `DEBUG = True`, then Django shows the yellow debug pages. Your `page_not_found` view is just rendering the 404 template, so I would remove it and the `handler404 = 'listings.views.page_not_found'` line. Then set `DEBUG = False` to test your `404.html` template. The code in `page_not_found` code is out of date the way it uses `render_to_response`, so I wouldn't use any book/tutorial/answer that suggested doing that.

Comment: I tried it like I said delete the function and replace it with another code and not activate the DEBUG and also deleted the URL but a white window appears error 500 and the page does not appear page in the project folder

Comment: You are still using `render_to_response` which is obsolete. You could use `return render(request, '404.html', status_code=404)`. But as I said, you don't need to set `handler404` or `handler500`. The custom views aren't doing anything special so you should remove them, and just override the 404.html and 500.html templates.